# Is there a list that contains most known dangerous user inputs? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, security, api, brute-force

I built an API and I would like to test it.
I already did my tests but I want to make sure that it is somehow secure by `brute forcing` it with a common list of **known dangerous user inputs**
It is written in PHP and MySql
Some of you might disagree whether brute force is a good practice here or not, but it's an extra safety measure

Comment: *brute forcing* has little to do with user inputs

Comment: All the user inputs are dangerous. If you treat any input as safe - you're in trouble.

Comment: The technique you should be looking at is "Fuzz Testing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OWASP provides a pretty good cheat sheet that might answer your questions: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Hmm: "If you're using an ORM (like Doctrine) in your PHP project, you're mostly prone to SQL attacks". Anyone got an edit account? `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Its obvious when you make application you want to make it secure. This was my concern too. For this i had made thorough research and collected information that helps protect PHP website.

> POINTS TO BE CONSIDERED FOR PHP APPLICATION SECURITY
>
> 1. Use  strong password encryption
>
> a. Use password salting for strong encryption.
>
> **2.  Never trust user inputs. Consider every variable viz $_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, $_SESSION, $_SERVER as if they were tainted. Use appropriate
>   filtering measure for these variables.**
>
> 1. To avoid XSS attack use php’s builtin functions htmlentities, strip_tags, etc while inserting the user input data into the database.
>      [function(3)  below will fix this issue]
> 2. Use custom sanitize function to avoid sql injection and other malicious activities.
> 3. Disable Register Globals in PHP.INI
> 4. Disable “allow_url_fopen” in PHP.INI
> 5. Don’t store sensitive data in cookies, as cookie can be stolen.
> 6. Check for hex code attacks. Clean the user input to filter hex codes.
>
> **9.  Don’t allow user to input more data than required. Validate input to allow max number of characters. Also validate each field for
>   relevant datatypes.**
>
> 1. Disable error reporting after Development period. It might give information about database that’ll be useful to hackers.
> 2. Hide file extension in browser. Use url rewriting techniques.
> 3. For login system, disable user after X failed login attempts.
> 4. Logging IP Address for each login.
> 5. For all logins, make system so that user must change their password after X number of days for security reason.
> 6. In admin panel, report should be available for each logins (failed logins, log in attempts, etc).  Note:- This will be helpful to track
>      the IP that makes frequent failed login attempts to the system. And we
>      can ban such IPs via .htaccess from accessing the system.
> 7. Auto logging out users from the system after X minutes of idle period.
> 8. When user request for a password change, deny user from keeping previous passwords.
> 9. Disable php functions like exec, eval, shell_exec etc. from the server.
> 10. Server directory security.  Disable directory listing via .htaccess. Put index.html file in each directory like images, css,
>       documents, etc.
> 11. Make following settings on PHP.INI (In production Server)
>
> a.    Disable allow_url_encode b. Display_errors = off  c.    Log_errors =
>   on d. Log_errors_max_len = 0 e.   Ignore_repeated_errors = off
>   f.    Ignored_repeated_source = off g.    Track_errors = off
>
> 1. Use one time token while posting a form. If token exist and matches the form post is valid otherwise invalid.

```
PHP Code : $token = md5 (uniqid (rand (), true)); $_SESSION[“token”] =
> $token;
```

> 

```
> HTML Code : <form> <input type=”hidden” name=”token” value=”<?php echo
> $token;?>”> </form>
```

> 1. Limit input field length to avoid BUFFER OVERFLOW ATTACK For Example:- PHP is a high level language, its memory allocation is not
>      limited, But by the end of day, when page is executed, it is APACHE
>      which handle things. Apache was made in C language, which has strict
>      rule about memory allocation. The large data in input field might make
>      impact on Apache’s behavior.
> 2. The lengths of database field for each datatype shouldnot exceed the actual requirement.
> 3. Hackers’ Policy – “If you can’t beat them, shut them down” For Example:- Must check users’ IP who is accessing the application. If
>      hackers’ can’t get into the application to ruin, they will certainly
>      try to make negative impact on the application to their level best.
>      They’ll try to execute application in an infinite loop. This will slow
>      down the application, drain server bandwidth and sometimes even crash
>      the server. Hence, keeping track of these activity will avoid from
>      massive loss..
> 4. Disable all unwanted and unused php extensions and modules from PHP.INI for performance reason.  For Example:- If we use mysql as
>      database, there is no sense in enabling postgre, sqllite, mssql and
>      oracle database extensions.
> 5. Avoid using Deprecated PHP Functions. Note:- Deprecated functions are no more supported by PHP Team. So, it’s wise to avoid using
>      deprecated functions.
> 6. Some serious mistake developers make. Example:. When passing around record ID’s in the query string for edition, not checking to
>      make sure they are  a)    Valid (that record exists), and  b) The record
>      belongs to the user requesting it, or the user has permission to view
>      that record.
> 7. A Good Web Host. Note: Most of the time even application being securely coded, the problems and issues might come from bad web host.
>      If application is hosted on Remote server, getting a good web host
>      with a reputation for security is essential. Say NO to shared hosting.
>
> For Example: There are many cases when people report that “my site was
>   hacked” when in actual fact its that their shared hosting allowed
>   another user on the same server to escalate their privileges.
>
> 1. Disabling foreign IPs. If an application is required to be run from certain place only, then disabling IPs other than that of this
>      certain place.
> 2. Using of Stored Procedures Using stored procedures will highly increase the security. Otherwise use Parameterized query if we’re
>      using raw query.
> 3. Testing The Application: Testing the application by inputing haphazard values. This should be done by someone who is not in
>      development team.
> 4. Point to remember. Whether we use .NET, Java or PHP, security issue is not the problem with language we choose. Security issue is
>      the problem due to the way application is programmed. With bad
>      programming even .NET and Java application are equally vulnerable.
> 5. Encrypting PHP Code Encrypt php code in production server using encrypting tool like IONCUBE (http://www.ioncube.com/), to make php
>      code safe from unauthorized changes. IONCUBE costs $199 at the time of
>      writing this document.
> 6. Use available tools like Havij, Acunetix, Netsparker, etc to check vulnerability in the application. And hiring someone expert in hacking
>      web applications will be much beneficial.

Comment: @Gumbo, I have gone through more than 100s of websites, pdf documents, etc, I haven't noted those links. Each site I visited, if I find anything useful, I just copied them down in a word document. I didnt feel necessary to track websites.

Comment: "To avoid XSS attack use php’s builtin functions htmlentities, strip_tags, etc while inserting the user input data into the database. [function(3) below will fix this issue]" --- this is terrible advice

Comment: "Use custom sanitize function to avoid sql injection and other malicious activities." --- this is terrible advice

Comment: "Check for hex code attacks. Clean the user input to filter hex codes." --- this is terrible advice

Comment: "For login system, disable user after X failed login attempts." --- this is terrible advice

Comment: "Auto logging out users from the system after X minutes of idle period." --- this is terrible advice

Comment: "Encrypting PHP Code Encrypt php code in production server using encrypting tool like IONCUBE (http://www.ioncube.com/), to make php code safe from unauthorized changes. IONCUBE costs $199 at the time of writing this document." --- this is terrible advice

Comment: @zerkms, In my solution the one in bold is his actual solution, rest of the point I posted for reference, who might come to this page someday. Can you tell me and explain why the points you mentioned in your comments are terrible advices?? It would be better if you shed light on this because even I will get right advice from you or may be the wrong one.

Comment: @LoVeSmItH: I don't see how to do that in a convenient way. Definitely not in the comments ;-)

Comment: @zerkms, well I have collected these points when I was doing a government project, they were much concerned about web security. So i collected these points. And I tried to find feasible solution for each points that can be easily implemented in the application. Its likely everyone may not need all points in every project. But as a precaution, one can learn a lot from the points I collected, at least I guess.

Comment: @LoVeSmItH: the issue is - the advices I marked a **NO-NO-NO**. They are evil and newbie, being not enough competent to know what is good and what is bad, may follow the terrible wrong advice.